# Java Sharing getters, setters, attributes but not the anotations

Tags: java, object, annotations

I have this code (just multiply the number of attributes by ALOT):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@Immutable
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    public static final String PROPERTYNAME_ID = "id";

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

/* used by JPA, needs to have same getters/setters as MyEntity */
public class MyEntityCriteria { 

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to share the attributes, getters and setters between those class?? ('extends' doesn't work as it also shares annotations...)

Comment: If you have many cases like this and there are common patterns, code generation is often the way to go. That is, make the *.java files that are inputs to "javac" be the outputs of some other process that automates the generation of your Java files.

Comment: You might take a look at either Groovy or Lombok.